# BoxLayout.encloseX is not working in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add buttons in SwipeableContainer as below.But it gives compile time error.

> "Exception: java.lang.Error - Unresolved compilation problem: The
>   method encloseX(Button, Button, Button, Button) is undefined for the
>   type BoxLayout java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem."

Code:

```
Button button1 = new Button("B1");
Button button2 = new Button("B2");
Button button3 = new Button("B3");
Button button4 = new Button("B4");
SwipeableContainer swipeableContainer = new SwipeableContainer(null,BoxLayout.encloseX(button1,button2,button3,button4), rowContainer);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated latest lib for codenameone and it's working.